# Binding Combobox Using Dictionary as the Datasource

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox, datasource

I'm using .NET 2.0 and I'm trying to bind a combobox's Datasource to a sorted dictionary.

So the error I'm getting is "DataMember property 'Key' cannot be found on the Datasource".

```
        SortedDictionary<string, int> userCache = UserCache.getSortedUserValueCache();
        userListComboBox.DataSource = new BindingSource(userCache, "Key"); //This line is causing the error
        userListComboBox.DisplayMember = "Key";
        userListComboBox.ValueMember = "Value";
```

Answer (score 154, accepted):

```
SortedDictionary<string, int> userCache = new SortedDictionary<string, int>
{
  {"a", 1},
  {"b", 2},
  {"c", 3}
};
comboBox1.DataSource = new BindingSource(userCache, null);
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Key";
comboBox1.ValueMember = "Value";
```

But why are you setting the `ValueMember` to "Value", shouldn't it be bound to "Key" (and `DisplayMember` to "Value" as well)?

Comment: Well it shouldn't matter either way. But it might make more sense to switch the two around. However the problem I'm having is with "comboBox1.DataSource = new BindingSource(userCache, null);" I can't pull null there because it gives me an error.

Comment: "ArgumentException: Cannot bind to the new display member.  Parameter name: newDisplayMember."  I don't know what error user803952 got, but this is the error *I* got when I tried doing this with an `IDictionary<int, string>`.

Comment: This answer worked for me when I tried to bind a Dictionary<decimal, string> to a combobox and received the exception "Complex DataBinding accepts as a data source either an IList or an IListSource."

Comment: I had no problem using comboBox1.DataSource = new BindingSource(userCache, null);
if you think that it is the offending statement, you can try replacing it with : comboBox1.DataSource = userCache.Select(kv => new { Key = kv.Key, Value = kv.Value }).ToArray();

Comment: another thing you might want to try is to move the line comboBox1.DataSource = new BindingSource(userCache, null);
 down after you set the DisplayMember and ValueMember

Comment: @SorinComanescu please I just want to know and wish you update your answer of how can we read data back from database to `combobox` that is use dictionary

Comment: Sometimes, if DataSource were assigned before DisplayMember did, execution blocks at DisplayMember assignment line. To me, this works -- cBox.DataSource = null;       cBox.DisplayMember = "Value";      cBox.ValueMember = "Key";      cBox.DataSource = new BindingSource(dict, null); // @dmihailescu is right

Answer (score 24):

I used Sorin Comanescu's solution, but hit a problem when trying to get the selected value. My combobox was a toolstrip combobox. I used the "combobox" property, which exposes a normal combobox.

I had a

```
 Dictionary<Control, string> controls = new Dictionary<Control, string>();
```

Binding code (Sorin Comanescu's solution - worked like a charm):

```
 controls.Add(pictureBox1, "Image");
 controls.Add(dgvText, "Text");
 cbFocusedControl.ComboBox.DataSource = new BindingSource(controls, null);
 cbFocusedControl.ComboBox.ValueMember = "Key";
 cbFocusedControl.ComboBox.DisplayMember = "Value";
```

The problem was that when I tried to get the selected value, I didn't realize how to retrieve it. After several attempts I got this:

```
 var control = ((KeyValuePair<Control, string>) cbFocusedControl.ComboBox.SelectedItem).Key
```

Hope it helps someone else!

Comment: This works, i have used the following in my own code to get it to work. https://gist.github.com/psykzz/5374823

Comment: You can also do it like this (getting the selected value): 
var value = comboBox.SelectedItem; 
var someItem = value.GetType().GetProperty("Key").GetValue(value, null);

Comment: The last line could also be reduced to: var control = ((KeyValuePair<Control, string>) cbFocusedControl.ComboBox.SelectedItem).Key; 1) unnecessary outer parentheses, 2) the compiler knows the Key is a Control already because it is casting to KeyValuePair<Control, string>, so the cast to Control is not needed.

Comment: Instead of all that, why couldn't you just use `cbFocusedControl.ComboBox.SelectedText` and `cbFocusedControl.ComboBox.SelectedValue` to get the DisplayMember and ValueMember respectively?

Answer (score 6):

```
        var colors = new Dictionary < string, string > ();
        colors["10"] = "Red";
```

Binding to Combobox

```
        comboBox1.DataSource = new BindingSource(colors, null);
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Value";
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "Key";
```

Full Source...[Dictionary as a Combobox Datasource](http://csharp.net-informations.com/dataset/dataset-combobox.htm)

Jeryy

Answer (score 5):

```
userListComboBox.DataSource = userCache.ToList();
userListComboBox.DisplayMember = "Key";
```

Comment: Clean and simple.

Answer (score 2):

A dictionary cannot be directly used as a data source, you should do more.

```
SortedDictionary<string, int> userCache =  UserCache.getSortedUserValueCache();
KeyValuePair<string, int> [] ar= new KeyValuePair<string,int>[userCache.Count];
userCache.CopyTo(ar, 0);
comboBox1.DataSource = ar; new BindingSource(ar, "Key"); //This line is causing the error
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Value";
comboBox1.ValueMember = "Key";
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a pretty old topic, but I also had a same problem.

My solution:

how we fill the combobox:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> item in listRegion)
{
    combo.Items.Add(item.Value);
    combo.ValueMember = item.Value.ToString();
    combo.DisplayMember = item.Key.ToString();
    combo.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

and that's how we get inside:

```
 MessageBox.Show(combo_region.DisplayMember.ToString());
```

I hope it help someone

Answer (score 1):

If this doesn't work why not simply do a foreach loop over the dictionary adding all the items to the combobox?

```
foreach(var item in userCache)
{
    userListComboBox.Items.Add(new ListItem(item.Key, item.Value));
}
```

Comment: Binding and adding items is not the same thing. Well, maybe that's what the OP really needs, who knows? ;)

Comment: I know but I don't see any code that is dependent on the databinding itself.

Comment: Well what you suggested would work, but the "new ListItem" exists in the System.Web.UI.WebControls Namespace  and I wouldn't import that for a windows form application.

Comment: I wouldn't do that either, I assume there's a winforms equivalent though? I'm not that into winforms.

Comment: new ComboBoxItem("itemtext","itemid");     can be used instead

Answer (score 0):

Use -->

```
comboBox1.DataSource = colors.ToList();
```

Unless the dictionary is converted to list, combo-box can't recognize its members.

Answer (score 0):

Just Try to do like this....

```
SortedDictionary<string, int> userCache = UserCache.getSortedUserValueCache();

    // Add this code
    if(userCache != null)
    {
        userListComboBox.DataSource = new BindingSource(userCache, null); // Key => null
        userListComboBox.DisplayMember = "Key";
        userListComboBox.ValueMember = "Value";
    }
```