# How to get value of SelectedValue in ComboBox filled with Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, combobox

We have dictionary like this:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, int> { { 0, 100 }, { 1, 202 }, { 2, 309 }, };
```

and so on a lot of values. dictionary binded to comboBox like this:

```
comboBox1.ItemsSource = dictionary;
comboBox1.DisplayMemberPath = "Value";
```

I'm wonder how can I get selectedvalue of this comboBox, if comboBox.Text works only for manually inputted values and this code:

```
string value = comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

return value like [1, 202], while I need clear int TValue "202". I'm unable to find similar question so I ask it there and hope that the answer may be useful for someone else.

Comment: Use this as an alternative to learning how to Create a `BindingSource` using a `Dictionary<int,int> or Dictionaryt<string, int>` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6412739/binding-combobox-using-dictionary-as-the-datasource

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looks like you have to cast `SelectedValue` into `KeyValuePair<int, int>`:

```
string value = ((KeyValuePair<int, int>)comboBox1.SelectedValue).Value.ToString();
```

However, you should put a brakepoint there and check what type `SelectedValue` really is.

I assume it's `KeyValuePair<int, int>` because your source collection is `Dictionary<int, int>` and because of output string for `SelectedValue.ToString()` which is `[1, 202]`.

Comment: Brilliant! Works great, thank you very much!! I will accept your answer asap.

Comment: It's better to use selecteditem as selectedvalue's type could be different if SelectedValuePath was specified

Answer (score 2):

If you specify the ValueMember, you can avoid the cast operation.
It's important that you set the path before the datasource, or it will fire the changed event with a selected value that is a keyvaluepair.

```
comboBox1.DisplayMemberPath = "Value";
comboBox1.SelectedValuePath= "Key";
comboBox1.ItemsSource = dictionary;
string value = comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();
```