# Load a ComboBox from Dictionary with BindingSource gives an ArgumentNullException

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I am trying to initialize a ComboBox from a Dictionary as follows:

```
Dictionary<string, int> TestDictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>
{
    {"Text1", 1},
    {"Text2", 2},
    {"Text3", 3}
};

testComboBox.DataSource = new BindingSource(TestDictionary, null);
```

But this throws the following exception:

[image: ArgumentNullException]

Comment: Possible duplicate, See here [binding-combobox-using-dictionary-as-the-datasource][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6412739/binding-combobox-using-dictionary-as-the-datasource

Answer (score 0):

Why are you binding it to a null?
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
You want this guy

```
BindingSource(IContainer)
```

not this one

```
BindingSource(Object, String)
```

Since

```
public BindingSource(
    Object dataSource,
    string dataMember
)
```

dataMember is used by your combobox.

```
dataMember
Type: System.String
The specific column or list name within the data source to bind to.
```

Or give it a proper name.

UPD/Correction:

According to the comment up top, you need to map these two:

```
testComboBox.DisplayMember = "Value";
testComboBox.ValueMember = "Key";
```

Comment: I tried that but Collections.Generic.Dictionary does not implement the ComponentModel.IContainer interface.