# How do I identify the selected ComboBox's Item relating it to a set of data?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

Suppose I have a fixed set of identifiers organized in, for example, a dictionary.

```
public static Dictionary<int, string> clientIds = new Dictionary<int, string>()
{
    { 0, "aa" },
    { 1, "ab"  },
    { 2, "ac" },
    { 3, "ba" },
    { 4, "bb" }
};
```

Then, I dynamically, at runtime, add to a `ComboBox` "friendly names" that are related to those identifiers (I don't know, however, which ones will be added.

```
clientIdCombo.Add(friendlyName);
```

Suppose that, at index zero, the friendly name "Alpha Beta" is added. That would relate to "ab" identifier. How can I know the user has selected the "ab" identifier, without having to condition based off the text displayed on the combo to the user? I tried using a `BindingList` instead, but that only provides me with that displayed text as well.

It sounds like something simple - how can I add underlying data to each `ComboBox` index? The simplest possible approach would be preferable, though multiple solutions are welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: Just use selected item index as a dictionary key...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6412739/binding-combobox-using-dictionary-as-the-datasource#6412893

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Binding Combobox Using Dictionary as the Datasource](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6412739/binding-combobox-using-dictionary-as-the-datasource)

Comment: @apocalypse But I don't know at what index an item will be added, this happens at runtime based on user input.

Comment: @JohnsonWhitler: then try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3063320/combobox-adding-text-and-value-to-an-item-no-binding-source

Comment: Where is your friendlyname stored and how it is related to the ids? idon't see it there? do you have some object that contain both the friendly_name and the ids?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ComboBox` items may be of any type you like and the items' display name would be defined by this type's `ToString` method.

This means you may define your item type like this:

```
class ClientItem
{
    public int Index;
    public string Id;
    public string FriendlyName;
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return FriendlyName;
    }
}
```

And fill your combo box with instances of this class.

```
comboBox.Items.Add(new ClientItem { 
    Index = 1,
    Id = "ab",
    FriendlyName = "Alpha Beta",
});
```

Then you can use the combo box items accessing all item's data. Just remember to cast to the specific item type:

```
var client = comboBox.SelectedItem as ClientItem;
MessageBox.Show(client.Id + ": " + client.FriendlyName);
```

Comment: Great solution, thanks. Alternatively, is it possible to simply assign ComboBox.DisplayMember and ComboBox.ValueMember to a generic variable?

Answer (score 1):

Just add as many items to the ComboBox as there are in the array, each with its corresponding text and **in the same order that they are on the array**. Then, when you want to get the selected item from the array, get the selected index using `ComboBox.SelectedIndex` and get the item from the array corresponding to that index. In your case you are using a int-indexed dictionary, which behaves like an array in terms of indexing it.

TLDR:

```
string[] array = new[] { "aa", "ab", "ac" };

//This array is "equivalent" to
Dictionary<int, string> dic= new Dictionary<int, string>()
{
    { 0, "aa" },
    { 1, "ab" },
    { 2, "ac" },
};

//Add the items to your ComboBox, for simplicity let's use this
ComboBox.Items.Add("Alfa Alfa");
ComboBox.Items.Add("Alfa Bravo");
ComboBox.Items.Add("Alfa Charlie");

//Later, when retrieving the selected item
int selIndex = ComboBox.SelectedIndex;
string selItem = array[selIndex];
```

Comment: That's an approach in case you're sure to add ALL the items you have on the ComboBox. In my scenario, I don't know which will be added, for example "Alfa Alfa" may not be added, but I won't know that until runtime, which makes retrieval based upon SelectedIndex alone impossible.